# How to protect my sensitive electronics from noise induced by AC power line?

Tags: noise, mains, isolation

I have a circuit that will be placed in somewhat close proximity to 220 VAC mains power. The mains power lines are bundled together of around 20 pairs (live and neutral) those 20 pairs should total up to around 50A max. My circuit will be reading the current consumption of those lines using a non-invasive current transformers which will then be read by my circuit. The circuit uses precision components which can be sensitive to voltage induced by those power lines.

How do you recommend to protect my circuit from those noise?

My first idea is to shield it with a Faraday cage, but making my own Faraday cage seems to be inelegant, I was thinking to somehow hide it. I thought if I place it in one of those small metal control boxes such as these:

[image]

Do these control boxes protect from outside noise? Most Faraday cages I see are in mesh form factor but it should work the same way as these boxes, right?

Comment: Are the circuits the same as the ones that use the ADS1115 (as per your earlier question)?

Comment: @Andyaka yes they are the one, alongside other complimentary circuits

Comment: What signal input voltage range are you looking at (smallest and biggest if you have that figured out yet)?

Comment: @Andyaka the absolute range is  0 to 3.3 in single ended mode and -1.65 to +1.65 volts, both modes will be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Are the circuits the same as the ones that use the ADS1115 (as per your earlier question)?
```

> *@Andyaka yes they are the one, alongside other complimentary circuits
>   – Jake quin*

### First, the input protection circuits

Given that your input circuits look like this: -

[image]

And the TI data sheet says: -

> These filter resistors produce a voltage drop because of the input
>   currents flowing into and out of the ADC. This voltage drop could
>   contribute to an additional gain error. Limit the filter resistor
>   values to below 1 kΩ.

I would go for something higher than 100 ohm for R62 to R63 - possibly 470 ohm or 680 ohm.

The TI data sheet also tells us that the absolute maximum current into these pins is 10 mA (absolute maximum ratings) and so this allows the real external inputs to be 4.7 volts to 6.8 volts either side of the supply rails used for the device. In other words, with only 100 ohm resistors you get a headroom of only 1 volt and I would want to ensure this was maximized without compromising performance so, 470 ohm or 680 ohm would seem sensible.

Because you have now given yourself this headroom, you can put TVS diodes on those external inputs to dirty digital ground with no risk of attenuating or clipping the signals you wish to monitor. You could use 6 to 10 volt TVS diodes and further protect those inputs. This is something I would consider anyway.

### The main question:

> *My first idea is to shield it with a Faraday cage, but making my own
>   Faraday cage seems to be inelegant, i was thinking to somehow hide it.
>   I thought if I place it in one of those small metal control boxes*

Yes, they actually do a good job of protecting against electric fields and, if they are made of steel/iron will also do a good job of reducing low frequency magnetic field interference that a non ferrous metal cabinet wouldn't cope with at all well.

Comment: Thank you for going the extra way of giving furthur protection to my circuit good sir. For the resistor I assume that you used 60Hz as the cutoff value (470 ohms, 5.6uF , 60 Hz or 680 ohms, 3.9uF , 60 Hz . You even chose a resistor value that the differential cap value is standard), are mains frequency that reliable and its okay to place no headroom ? like for say 65Hz or 70Hz?

Comment: @Jakequin I didn't recalculate the capacitors because I couldn't remember what your peak operating frequency is. At the moment you have a cut-off frequency of 3617 Hz and, if you want to keep that, the 0.22 uF capacitor needs to reduce by the amount that each resistor increases in order to maintain the same CR time. You should also reduce the 22 nF capacitors by the same ratio.

Comment: However, if you can get away with a longer CR time then you should do so but, remember, if you are measuring 50/60 Hz and digitizing you might want to also adequately digitize any harmonics so reducing the cut-off frequency may not be such a good idea.

Comment: Ohhh so thats how you did it. I already accepted the fact that i wont be able to fully sample the current, the chip can only sample 1Hz 13-14 times max (860sps). Actually I did not account for harmonics ! .My original idea was to use a set number of samples to reconstruct a 60Hz wave and calculate from that.I might have to rethink on how i would calculate current used in a line. With harmonics in mind at which point should i stop?  Given that the base is 60Hz and my max sampling rate of 860 i should be able to measure upto 7th harmonic( 420Hz) is anything wrong with this analogy?

Comment: How long is a piece of string. I normally advise anyone measuring current to sample at 1 kSps or above to account for significant harmonics but that's at 50 Hz and so 60 Hz would be proportionately higher. If you're not too bothered about harmonics then try and filter as close to 60 Hz as possible in order to reduce harmonics causing aliasing.

Comment: not considering harmonics when i was choosing the adc was a laps of mine. I think with this version of the circuit i will do just as what you have and filter close to 60hz. I was looking for for some TVS diodes and this [IC](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PCMFXHDMI2S_SER.pdf) showed up, can this be suitable replacement for the diodes?

Comment: Can you solder bump packages? Also, it's only got a 5 volt stand off and the reason for making the resistors bigger in value was to allow you to choose something that is closer to 10 volts hence, it will pretty much not conduct any measurable current from the signal.

Comment: I can confidently solder BGAs as long as they dont have a lot of pads. These IC have chokes in them is that good if used in this case? if not ill stop looking for ready made IC and just go with the diodes

Comment: You need to be looking for a device with a stand off voltage greater than 7 volts in my opinion. I think they might leak too much with just 5 volt stand off voltage. Also, you don’t really want to be choosing a device that is too specialist footprint wise.

Comment: if included choke are not important i have found [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2e007.pdf). Would it matter if its unidirectional? I apologize this is my first time using TVS's.

Comment: That doesn't break down until 13 volts and that is too high. With 13 volts clamped at an external input over 10 mA is flowing through the resistors into the ADS1115 inputs and this is too much. You need to find a device that is 6 to 10 volts clamping or hold-off voltage.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply, had to work something out past days. So i watched some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k301-A-rEe8&list=PL7UxqUbRbxBcM-ukMB0hdMW_iqDuvkUbH&index=3&t=0s) about ESD to get a better understanding of tvs diode. with that in mind i would like to ask how did you come up with the values, so that i may replicate it in future projects. You mention first that i have to find a stand-off voltage also known as working voltage of about 6-10v and 5.5v is too low, why do i need the extra over head when if my chip Vcc is 3.3v and theoretically any more would destroy the pin ?

Comment: I think understand the why the breakdown voltage has to be low,  the breakdown voltage is where the diode will start to conduct so we have to make sure that the pin of the ADC will not go over 10mA (the pins max current). Assuming the V=I*R, where R=is 680 ohms and I = 10ma then v=6.8 volts breakdown is rating that i should look for

Comment: for uni directional vs bi directional , bi directional seems to work better with differential signals that goes to negative voltage. For hold off voltage or clamp, this is the voltage that the ADC will be exposed to when an ESD occurs, but since there is a resistor  in series of the pin there will be kind of a voltage divider and the ADC will recieve less voltage. So if i use this [IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2e009.pdf), it has a sharp curv of the current clamp that mean for a wide range of ESD amp i would get about around 8volt that can go through

Comment: I have made adjustment to the [circuit](https://ibb.co/KL9zjYf) with updated values 700 resistor value to match the breakdown voltage of 7 so that 10mA would pass to the pin and the tvs should catch anything beyond. 3.3uf for the capacitor to come as close to 60 herz (68 exact value) as 3.9uf would be short by 2 hertz. and a differential cap of 33uf as the datasheet said that x10 to the common mode capacitor

Comment: Your signal rises to 3.3 volts but a 4 or 5 volt TVS might still conduct a little bit at 3.3 volts and I wanted to avoid this. If your signal can cope with a few odd mA extra current at 3.3 volts then you are fine to choose lower value TVS. You don't need to be so close to 60 Hz because you will start to possible unreasonably attenuate your signal. Of course if aliasing might be a problem then maybe you do.

Comment: I see, we dont want the original voltage to be affected due to the tvs conducting we want it as high of an impedance as possible . Im having trouble looking for an IC that fits the 6-10v of standoff and clamp. I am curious how di you came up with the standoff voltage value that i need that much extra headroom ? is it from experience or is possible to compute it with datasheet values?

Comment: Experience tells me that a TVS or zener having a clamp voltage close to the signal peak may conduct several mA at that signal peak. That’s the whole reason why I suggested bigger values for the series resistors. Don’t skimp on this is my personal advice. Fit standard TVS diodes if you can’t find a suitable chip. Single part diodes will have a much superior power rating when it comes to surges.

Comment: I will follow your advice. how do you usually pick the value for the headroom, aside from the breakdown voltage that need to be a value that must prevent extra current from going through the pin, for the standoff and clamp do you usuall pick twice the expected values? can you over do this? or you can go as high as possible as long the breakdown voltage fit the needs

Comment: Split the difference between maximum voltage before more than 10 mA flows into the input and your peak signal level. Round down. You don’t need bidirectional devices either. There is a more long winded way but, given the new chance of using TVS diodes due to the increase in resistance, a halfway split is going to be reasonable. If it were a big volume design then there’d be more calculations and a proper analysis of potential surge energy currents but, that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: So assuming a single ended ADC pin(not necessarily the ads1115) max current is 10mA which in series with a 700 ohm filter resistor. max voltage to produce 10mA is 7v, peak signal voltage is 3.3. By splitting the difference (7-3.3)/2 is 1.85 volts. so for a 3.3 peak signal i should choose 5.15‬v of working/clamp voltage? is that correct?

Comment: No, you choose the resistor so that 10 mA doesn’t flow into the input when the input voltage is greater than the supply rail of the chip plus about 0.3 volts. Maybe the ADC has a supply voltage of 5 volts (I can’t remember) but you need to exceed this plus around 0.3 volts to start pushing current into the input circuit. Then you add an extra voltage of 10mA times the series input resistor to define the actual raw input voltage that can push 10 mA into that input. It’s late and maybe what I’ve written doesn’t appear that clear so sorry for that. Try again tomorrow!

Comment: If the supply to the chip is 5 volts and the resistor is 700 ohms then  the limit is 7 volts plus 5 volts plus 0.3 volts which equals 12.3 volts. That’s the upper limit for the TVS voltage.

Comment: Just noticed (from original question) that the ADS1115 supply is 3.3 volts hence, if an input rose to about 3.6 volts (0.3 volts higher than Vcc) it would be at the point of conducting current due to internal schottky diodes. So, if your external resistor is 700 ohms and we assumed that 10 mA were flowing in it (the limit for the ADS1115 inputs) then the maximum voltage we can tolerate is 3.6 volts plus 700*0.01 volts  = 10.6 volts. So, in simple terms you should aim for a TVS that operated at 6.95 volts (6.8 volts would be good). Hope that is cleared up. Link me the device you choose.

Comment: Please do reply at your comfortable time. I cant thank you enough for teaching me this much. oh ! alright i got it when you first clarified it. This [IC](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/BZA462A-115/1727-2087-1-ND/5221685) seems to be the closest i can get to our desired value

Comment: Important numbers in data sheet: 700 nA max at 4 volts = good. 200 pF capacitance max = good. This is an ESD protection device that is suitable!

Comment: However, if you were looking for a TVS that could protect against indirect lightning surges you might choose one like in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462294/deep-explanation-on-tvs-diode-voltage-suppression/462296#462296). Maybe you should raise a question about TVS diodes if you feel up for it. A TVS diode is designed to cope with a certain type of surge be it ESD or indirect lightning - it's a kind of guarantee against certain requirements specified by all manner of specification writers but ESD and surges are the most common.

Comment: I dont think i would go ahead and protect it against lightning, aside that its isolated, the lightning will need to hit the control box first (which is earthed) if it can even hit the control box. and if it passes through the mains voltage and through the transformer clamps they will saturate anyway. In short even all that and it can still go through all that, everything else is pretty much fried at that point.

Comment: Just a thought: ethernet is protected against lightning surges. Not via an explicit use of TVS diodes but by the magnetics. You'd be surprised at what common electrical interconnections have to be protected against indirect lightning surges. Clearly direct lightning surges means death to electronics.

Comment: Thank you again good sir, you have taught me so much. I feel like i learned enough to make an ADC circuit that is on par with oscilloscopes, i might be biting more than i can chew there, but thats what i feel. Again thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If these control boxes are conductive, then you can use them as a faraday cage. Because the mains power lines are very low frequency (50Hz/60Hz), you do not have to consider the skin-effect, which reduces shielding quality for high frequency signals. A conductive box of any kind will work perfectly. You could even use some aluminium foil to wrap your circuit into.

Comment: Yes they are metal that are powder coated, would the boxes need to be earthed?

Comment: The safety regulations normally require these boxes to be earthed in the proximity of mains.  Also ensure that the door and the frame is connected with an earth wire.  Magnetic shielding might also be required.